# JQuery stop event bubbling from method call

Tags: jquery, plugins, event-bubbling

I am trying to get my head around the jquery plugin structure and wrote the following HTML code which forms the start of a slideshow:

```
<div id="bubble" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background: #ccc;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#bubble").bubble();
    });
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

This is linked to the following jquery plugin code:

```
(function($){
var i = 0;

var methods = {
    mouseup: function(e){
        $(this).bubble('next');
        e.stopPropagation();
    },
    mousedown: function(e){
        $(this).bubble('next');
        e.stopPropagation();
    },
    next: function(){
        console.log(i++);
    }
};

$.fn.bubble = function(method){
    $(this).bind("mouseup", methods.mouseup)
          .bind("mousedown", methods.mousedown);

    if ( methods[method] ) {
    return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } 
};

})(jQuery);
```

I'm not sure why but clicking the bubble box calls multiple iterations of the next: method. Is there a way to limit the number of calls to the next: method?

Answer (score 1):

You are binding `mousedown` and `mouseup` to the `next` function, this will send two `next` functions per click, I don't think you are meaning to do that.

In order to fix it, remove one of the binds, or just bind `click`.

Comment: what he says,  a mouse click consists of both a mousedown and a mouseup event, if you bind both it will fire twice. jquery has the 'click' event this should be enough.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k3FhM/1/ only binding mouse up removes the iteration problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use [stopImmediatePropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) so that you just log twice (because you call next() twice):

```
(function($){
var i = 0;

var methods = {
    mouseup: function(e){
        $(this).bubble('next');
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    },
    mousedown: function(e){
        $(this).bubble('next');
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    },
    next: function(){
        console.log(i++);
    }
};

$.fn.bubble = function(method){
    $(this).bind("mouseup", methods.mouseup)
          .bind("mousedown", methods.mousedown);

    if ( methods[method] ) {
    return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    }
};

})(jQuery);
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k3FhM/